# SQL Server: Multiple Output Clauses

Tags: sql-server, output-clause

I have two tables, `Table_1` and `Table_2`.

`Table_1` has columns `PK` (autoincrementing `int`) and `Value` (`nchar(10)`).

`Table_2` has `FK` (`int`), `Key` (`nchar(10)`) and `Value` (`nchar(10)`).

That is to say, `Table_1` is a table of data and `Table_2` is a key-value store where one row in `Table_1` may correspond to 0, 1 or more keys and values in `Table_2`.

I'd like to write code that programmatically builds up a query that inserts one row into `Table_1` and a variable number of rows into `Table_2` using the primary key from `Table_1`.

I can do it easy with one row:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 ([Value])
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK, 'Test1Key', 'Test1Val' INTO Table_2 (FK, [Key], [Value])
VALUES ('Test')
```

But SQL doesn't seem to like the idea of having multiple rows. This fails:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 ([Value])
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK, 'Test1Key', 'Test1Val' INTO Table_2 (FK, [Key], [Value])
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK, 'Test2Key', 'Test2Val' INTO Table_2 (FK, [Key], [Value])
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK, 'Test3Key', 'Test3Val' INTO Table_2 (FK, [Key], [Value])
VALUES ('Test')
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: [Read the MSDN documentation on the `OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) - you can output multiple rows into e.g. a temporary table (or a table variable - or directly into a target table, too!)

Comment: I've read that but may have missed what you're referring to. Outputting something liked INSERTED.* isn't really appropriate here because I only want to output the value from one inserted row, multiple times. I don't suppose you could give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to put the code in answer, in comment it looks ugly...

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp(PK int, value nchar(10))

INSERT INTO Table_1 ([Value])
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK, inserted.[Value] INTO #Tmp
SELECT 'Test'

INSERT INTO Table_2 (FK, [Key], Value)
SELECT PK, 'Test1Key', 'Test1Val' FROM #Tmp
UNION ALL SELECT PK, 'Test2Key', 'Test2Val' FROM #Tmp
UNION ALL SELECT PK, 'Test3Key', 'Test3Val' FROM #Tmp
```

Btw, SQL Server won't let you do it all in one query without some ugly hack...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `INSERTED.PK` value into a parameter, then inserting into table 2 with 3 `INSERT..VALUES` or 1 `INSERT..SELECT` statement.