# Multiple OUTPUT clauses in MERGE/INSERT/DELETE SQL commands?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `T-SQL` script that implements some synchronization logic using `OUTPUT` clause in `MERGE`s and `INSERT`s.

Now I am adding a logging layer over it and I would like to add a second `OUTPUT` clause to write the values into a report table.

I can add a second `OUTPUT` clause to my `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE TABLE_TARGET AS T
USING TABLE_SOURCE AS S
ON (T.Code = S.Code) 
WHEN MATCHED AND T.IsDeleted = 0x0
    THEN UPDATE SET ....
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT ....
OUTPUT inserted.SqlId, inserted.IncId
INTO @sync_table
OUTPUT $action, inserted.Name, inserted.Code;
```

And this works, but as long as I try to add the target

```
INTO @report_table;
```

I get the following error message before `INTO`:

```
A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semicolon (;)
```

I found [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094099/sql-server-multiple-output-clauses), but it didn't help me further, because the fields I am going to insert do not overlap between two tables and I don't want to modify the working sync logic (if possible).

**UPDATE:**

After the answer by [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) I had another idea and re-wrote my query as following:

```
INSERT INTO @report_table (action, name, code)
SELECT M.Action, M.Name, M.Code
FROM
(
MERGE TABLE_TARGET AS T
USING TABLE_SOURCE AS S
ON (T.Code = S.Code) 
WHEN MATCHED AND T.IsDeleted = 0x0
    THEN UPDATE SET ....
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT ....
OUTPUT inserted.SqlId, inserted.IncId
INTO @sync_table
OUTPUT $action as Action, inserted.Name, inserted.Code
) M
```

Unfortunately this approach did not work either, the following error message is output at runtime:

```
An OUTPUT INTO clause is not allowed in a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.
```

So, there is definitely no way to have multiple `OUTPUT` clauses in a single DML statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not possible. See the [grammar](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

The Merge statement has

```
[ <output_clause> ]
```

The square brackets show it can have an optional output clause. The grammar for that is

```
<output_clause>::=
{
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> INTO { @table_variable | output_table }
        [ (column_list) ] ]
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> ]
}
```

This clause can have both an `OUTPUT INTO` and an `OUTPUT` but not two of the same.

If multiple were allowed the grammar would have `[ ,...n ]`

Comment: Yes, I saw this on MSDN but hoped there would be a hack to overcome this limitation. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I'd add to this that you need to have the Output-Into come first BEFORE the Output (just as your grammar brackets show).  I mention this only in case someone has both in the wrong order and doesn't realize why it's not working for them.

Comment: It is possible to wrap `MERGE` into the stored procedure and use `INSERT ... EXEC` to insert the result of the second `OUTPUT` into a second table, as I've shown in my answer. It has its downsides, but may be useful in certain cases.

Answer (score 7):

The `OUTPUT` clause allows for a selectable list. While this doesn't allow for multiple result sets, it does allow for one result set addressing all actions.

```
<output_clause>::=
{
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> INTO { @table_variable | output_table }
        [ (column_list) ] ]
    [ OUTPUT <dml_select_list> ]
}
```

I overlooked this myself until just the other day, when I needed to know the action taken for the row didn't want to have complicated logic downstream.
The  means you have a lot more freedom here. I did something similar to the following which allowed me to use the output in a simple means:

```
DECLARE @MergeResults TABLE (
    MergeAction VARCHAR(50),
    rowId INT NOT NULL,
    col1 INT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(255) NULL
    )

MERGE INTO TARGET_TABLE AS t
    USING SOURCE_TABLE AS s
    ON t.col1 = s.col1
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET [col2] = s.[col2]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (
            [col1]
            ,[col2]
            )
        VALUES (
            [col1]
            ,[col2]
            )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN
        DELETE
OUTPUT $action as MergeAction, 
    CASE $action 
        WHEN 'DELETE' THEN deleted.rowId 
        ELSE inserted.rowId END AS rowId,
    CASE $action 
        WHEN 'DELETE' THEN deleted.col1 
        ELSE inserted.col1 END AS col1,
    CASE $action 
        WHEN 'DELETE' THEN deleted.col2 
        ELSE inserted.col2 END AS col2
    INTO @MergeResults;
```

You'll end up with a result set like:

```
| MergeAction | rowId | col1 | col2 |
| INSERT      | 3     | 1    | new  |
| UPDATE      | 1     | 2    | foo  |
| DELETE      | 2     | 3    | bar  |
```

Comment: How do you differentiate between Insert / Update into @MergeResults?

Answer (score 5):

Martin Smith is right, it is not possible to have two `OUTPUT INTO` clauses in one `MERGE` statement, but he is also right that it **is** possible to have one `OUTPUT INTO` and one `OUTPUT` clause. `OUTPUT INTO` inserts its result set directly into the given table and the simple `OUTPUT` returns result set to the caller.

So, you can wrap the `MERGE` statement into a stored procedure and then use `INSERT ... EXEC` to insert result set of the simple `OUTPUT` into a second table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestMerge]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    MERGE TABLE_TARGET AS T
    USING TABLE_SOURCE AS S
    ON (T.Code = S.Code) 
    WHEN MATCHED AND T.IsDeleted = 0x0
        THEN UPDATE SET ....
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
        THEN INSERT ....
    OUTPUT inserted.SqlId, inserted.IncId
    INTO sync_table
    OUTPUT $action AS MergeAction, inserted.Name, inserted.Code;
END
```

**Usage**

```
INSERT INTO report_table
EXEC [dbo].[TestMerge];
```

This will insert rows into `sync_table` and into `report_table`.

If you examine execution plan you'll see that `INSERT ... EXEC` creates a temporary table behind the scenes (see also [The Hidden Costs of INSERT EXEC](http://dataeducation.com/revisiting-isnull-coalesce-and-the-perils-of-micro-optimization/) by 
Adam Machanic).

Comment: The "normal" way to avoid the intermediate temp table between EXEC and INSERT is to convert the code to an in-line table-valued function.  Unfortunately, these are not allowed to have side-effects (like an insert!)  HOWEVER, you can get around this IF you're willing to code a streaming C# SQL CLR! It's a longish path, but do-able!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but I just ran into this issue and used a solution that's practical rather than technical, and may or may not be obvious.

As already discussed, MERGE isn't designed to do this.  The INSERT_INTO...EXEC solution is a good workaround, but the particular stored procedure on which I'm working is already complex enough.

So to keep things simple for the next guy who has to work on this code, I just used two MERGE statements...one that does the inserting and one that does the updating.  After all, there's no law that says you have to use only one.  I added an "action" column to the logging table, into which I have the MERGE statement insert either "Insert" or "Update" depending on what it's doing.

Performance doesn't take enough of a hit to worry about, especially since this isn't a user process.

TIP:  Do the update first, and the insert second.  Otherwise, when you do the first load, you'll get one insert record and one update record for every row you import.