# SQL Merge - Persist data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server 2014.

In my procedure, I have a `MERGE` statement and I have a question about it.

My `MERGE` statement has simple following structure:

```
MERGE dbo.T1 AS tgt
USING (SELECT ...) AS src ON ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ...

OUTPUT inserted.MyColumn
INTO @NewTable (MyColumnValue);
```

Just like how it populates a table for all inserts, I also need it to populate another table for all updates too.

Is is possible, and if yes then would you please let me know how?

Comment: OUTPUT $action, inserted.* and deleted.* will be updated for your columns, you can use $action to just pull the records from the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to direct the results to two tables. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165870/multiple-output-clauses-in-merge-insert-delete-sql-commands).

You can make the table wider and output both the `inserted` and `deleted` columns on the same row:

```
MERGE dbo.T1 AS tgt
USING (SELECT ...) AS src ON ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ...

OUTPUT $action, inserted.col1, inserted.col2, deleted.col1, deleted.col2
INTO @NewTable (action, inserted_col1, inserted_col2, deleted_col1, deleted_col2);
```

Then you can split `@NewTable` however you want.