# Multiple OUTPUTs with MERGE

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have a merge that looks likes this:

```
MERGE INTO TARGET_TABLE AS t
USING SOURCE_TABLE AS s
    ON t.LOCAL_ID = s.LOCAL_ID
WHEN MATCHED
    AND (
        t.[col1] <> s.[col1]
        OR t.[col2] <> s.[col2]
        OR t.[col5] <> s.[col5]
        )
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET [col1] = s.[col1]
            ,[col2] = s.[col2]
            ,[col5] = s.[col5]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (
            [LOCAL_ID]
            ,[col1]
            ,[col2]
            ,[col5]
            )
        VALUES (
            s.[LOCAL_ID]
            ,[col1]
            ,[col2]
            ,[col5]
            )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN
        DELETE
OUTPUT GetDate()
    ,s.LOCAL_ID
    ,$ACTION
    ,deleted.[col1] col1
    ,deleted.[col2] col2
    ,deleted.[col5] col5
    ,inserted.[col1] NEW_col1
    ,inserted.[col2] NEW_col2
    ,inserted.[col5] NEW_col5
INTO [AUDIT];
```

Which pushes a row into my `AUDIT` table that looks like this:

`LOCAL_ID ACTION col1 col2 col5 NEW_col1 NEW_col2 NEW_col5`

with some demo values:

`123 UPDATE foo bar foobar FOO BAR FOOBAR`

but what I'd really like it something like

```
123 UPDATE NEW FOO BAR FOOBAR
123 UPDATE OLD foo bar foobar
```

Where the output of the merge has one row for `deleted` values and one row for `inserted` values.

My first attempt at this was to use `OUTPUT` and `OUTPUT INTO` and then wrap it with an `INSERT` (See [Multiple OUTPUT clauses in MERGE/INSERT/DELETE SQL commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165870/multiple-output-clauses-in-merge-insert-delete-sql-commands) )  but SQL server says I cannot do this with error `An OUTPUT INTO clause is not allowed in a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.`

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I want without getting very messy?
I am hoping that the newer SQL server software addresses this in some way. I am using `SQL SERVER Enterprise 2012`

Comment: Does it have to all be done in one merge? I'm thinking (if this is the only way the table is updated), this may be more naturally done within a trigger.

Comment: You might be careful using MERGE. There are a number of bugs with that statement. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: @SeanLange almost all bugs are fixed. Aaron had a point but I think 7 years and 3 major releases after MERGE it's time to let this rest.

Comment: Almost all of the bugs except for things like upsert causing deadlocks which is probably the most common usage of MERGE, including the script posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output statement Include both Inserted columns and Deleted columns.

```
OUTPUT GETDATE(),
$Action
Deleted.Col1 as OldCol1,
Inserted.Col1 as NewCol1
INTO #tempTable...
```

Then do an Unpivot or Cross Apply linking the columns to the new and old values.