# SQL Merge Into with multiple statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to keep a historic table of another one. When updating the original I would like to insert rows into the historic one.
I'm using Sql Merge:

```
MERGE TargetProducts AS Target
USING SourceProducts    AS Source
ON Source.ProductID = Target.ProductID
    
-- For Inserts
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProductID,ProductName, Price) 
    VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, Source.Price)
    
-- For Updates
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    Target.ProductName  = Source.ProductName,
    Target.Price        = Source.Price
    
-- For Deletes
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
    DELETE;
```

Can I make multiple statements in the same "`when`" condition?, as such:

```
...
-- For Inserts
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProductID,ProductName, Price) VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, Source.Price);
    INSERT INTO anotherTable (OldProductID,OldProductName, OldPrice) VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, Source.Price);
...
```

Comment: FYI, you're reinventing the wheel - *system-versioned* tables have been part of the SQL standard for years are are supported by most RDBMS

Comment: @Stu Did I make such a claim? I asked whether it is possible or not to use multiple insert statements in the same `merge when match`.

Comment: @HenriquePombo - FYI just means For your Information, it's not a comment on your Merge statement but given the description of your intention is seems relevant and intended just to help, by all means ignore it.

Comment: Don't see if it's possible in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql). Besides triggering the 2nd insert in the AFTER INSERT trigger. But maybe I'll be proven wrong.

Comment: A DML statement can only affect *one* table, not many. If you're opposed to using temporal tables, as @Stu suggests, you'll need to implement triggers.

Comment: @Larnu, SQL Server has `OUTPUT` clause that makes it possible to insert into two tables in one statement. See my answer

Comment: Sort of, @VladimirBaranov . They are 2 separate DML statements, just nested. But yes, it is still one statement as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can `INSERT` only into one table. The syntax does not allow multiple statements in the same "when" condition.

But, SQL Server has `OUTPUT` clause which allows to add another table. It is very handy when you need to have some sort of auditing trail.

See this question [How to INSERT into multiple tables from one SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107078/how-to-insert-into-multiple-tables-from-one-select-statement)

So, add `OUTPUT` clause to your `MERGE` statement. Something like this:

```
MERGE TargetProducts AS Target
USING SourceProducts    AS Source
ON Source.ProductID = Target.ProductID
    
-- For Inserts
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProductID,ProductName, Price) 
    VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, Source.Price)
    
-- For Updates
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    Target.ProductName  = Source.ProductName,
    Target.Price        = Source.Price
    
-- For Deletes
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
    DELETE

OUTPUT inserted.ProductID, inserted.ProductName, inserted.Price
INTO anotherTable (OldProductID,OldProductName, OldPrice)
;
```

This will capture both updates and inserts in `anotherTable`. To capture only inserts you can output at first into a temp table and then filter results by MERGE `$action`.

Have a look at this question:

[Pipes and filters at DBMS-level: Splitting the MERGE output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533204/pipes-and-filters-at-dbms-level-splitting-the-merge-output-stream)